# Accessing SimpleCursorAdapter from all methods

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set a 'SimpleCursorAdapter' object variable  within my class so that all of the methods can access it, all very standard stuff. At the moment I'm getting an error within my 'OnCreate' method showing the following error:

Error:

```
cursorAdapter cannot be resolved to a type.
```

Heres the declared SimpleCursorAdapter within the class:

```
package com.example.flybase2;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ViewAppointments extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
ListView searchedAppView;
ImageButton searchAppoints;
EditText searchAppName;
Long id;



DBHandlerApp delApp = new DBHandlerApp(this, null, null);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.appointmentview);

    searchedAppView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    searchAppoints = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchAppointName); 
    searchAppName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputAppointName); 

    DBHandlerApp DBAppointments = new DBHandlerApp(this, null, null);

    DBHandlerApp searchApps = new DBHandlerApp(this, null, null);

    searchApps.open();


    Cursor cursor = searchApps.getAppointmentsData();
    searchApps.close();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);



    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    String [] from = new String [] {DBAppointments.KEY_NAMEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_TYPEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_TIMEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_DATEAPP, DBAppointments.KEY_COMMENTAPP};
    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtAppointName, R.id.txtAppointType, R.id.txtAppointTime, R.id.txtAppointDate, R.id.txtAppointCom};

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")


    //ERROR: cursorAdapter cannot be resolved.
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.setappointviews, cursor, from, to);
    searchedAppView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    searchedAppView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    searchAppoints.setOnClickListener(this);



    searchAppName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
     {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            cursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }

     });

    };
```

Comment: Did you import `android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter`? Have you cleaned your project recently?

Comment: @A--C I have imported 'import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;' I have cleaned the project and it makes no difference. Would it help if I posted my whole class?

Comment: Sure, it's certainly something really small.

Comment: @A--C I have added the whole class. I cant imagine why but Im wondering if my textwatcher being in the 'onCreate' method is causing issues? As currently this isnt working either. But then again thats probably becuase it cant see the cursorAdapter object!

Comment: Move all the `@SuppressWarnings()` on top of `onCreate()'s declaration, so don't have any annotations inside the method itself. Also, make sure that your class has its closing brace (the one you attached doesn't).

Comment: I never use `@SuppressWarnings`, so I have no idea why but it causes the error...

Comment: Also, you cannot initialize `delApp` outside of your methods, since it needs a valid Context. (Be wary any time you use `this` outside of your methods.) The earliest you can initialize `delApp` is _inside_ `onCreate()`.

Comment: @Sam Many thanks I gave put the new object instance within the onListItem click method. Out of interest can you see any reason my edittext filter the listview would not be working?

Comment: @A--C many thanks removing the warning made the variable visible. I want to mark your answer as correct but cannot. As I have asked of Sam can you see what my issue is with my filter of the edittext on my listview? Also if you answer below then I'll select your answer as correct.

Comment: @user1352057 I can't see anything wrong at first glance,but then again I haven't worked with filters, so I can't be sure.

Comment: The approach your are using should work for Adapters like ArrayAdapter. But to filter a CursorAdapter you need to create a FilterQueryProvider and an appropraite fetch method in your database adapter. Try [this tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue was with the location of the annotations.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

was inside `onCreate()` which (oddly) causes errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that object. You can do:

```
searchedAppView.getAdapter(); //listView.getAdapter()
```

wherever you want in your activity.